Split up sample into two sub-samples while ensuring that subjects in sub-samples are not related
I have a sample that I would like to split up into two roughly equally sized sub-samples. These sub-samples should be similar concerning a defined set of variables (e.g. age, gender, motion, etc.). Normally one could probably just use multivariate distance measurement to compute some sort of distance measurement between every pair of subjects which can then be used to split up the sample.
But in my case, I have two more problems:
1. I also have categorical variables (e.g. sex) that need to be considered when splitting up my sample. Classical distance measurements can only work with continuous variables (e.g. age). I already had the idea if one could use Gower's distance here?
2. I have an additional constraint. Some subjects come from the same family. Because I must assume that these subjects form clusters (also with respect to unobserved covariates), I want to make sure that none of the resulting sub-samples contain subjects that come from the same family. In case that there are more than three subjects from the same family, this of course means, that one ore more subjects would have to be dropped (i.e. they are not assigned to any of the two sub-samples).
Consider this example to give you a better intuition:



subject
family
age
gender
motion




1
a
24
1
0.75


2
a
12
0
0.32


3
a
23
1
0.87


4
b
13
1
0.65


5
b
40
0
0.11


6
c
23
1
0.2



As you can see three subjects come from family "a", two subjects come from family "b" and one subject comes from family "c". For family "a" we probably want to pick subject 1 for the first sub-sample, subject 3 for the second sub-sample, and drop subject 2. Subjects 4 and 5 must also be assigned to each of the sub-samples because they come from the same family "b". Finally, subject 6 is not related to anyone in the sample so we could freely assign it to any of the sub-samples.

Could you please explain why you are performing this sub-sampling?  Generally, any procedure that requires dropping data is almost guaranteed to be inferior to some other procedure having the same statistical objectives.

The idea is to have a discovery and a replication sample. I don't want to go into too much detail (my analysis is quite complex). Still, the rough idea is to use the discovery sample for feature selection and the replication sample to correlate these features with external variables. If I would use the whole sample I would be at risk of double-dipping, i.e. I would use the same sample to reduce my feature set and then correlate this feature set with other variables.

That would seem to lead to the opposite objective: if you wish the two subsamples to be as independent as possible, then wouldn't you want to include all members of a family within a single cluster?  Also, it's unclear why distance measurements would be relevant to this problem.

Some families are quite big (3-5 subjects belong to the same family). On top, some family members are monozygotic twins.  This (very loosely speaking) means that you have "clones" in your dataset (rows/subjects are not independent and therefore some clusters could drive correlations in downstream analyses). If I would use the whole sample I would have to use hierarchical resampling methods or other techniques that can control for these clusters in the dataset. A simple splitting method would be more easy in the downstream analyses (while paying the price of loosing subjects).
